# Catching workspace switching in GNOME

Tags: c++, c, gtk, gnome, kde-plasma

ALL,

In GNOME (or KDE) it is possible to switch between different workspaces by using Ctrl+Alt+Up_Arrow.

Is there any way to catch this event in my program? Is there a GTK+ (or Qt) signal that is sent out when this happens?

TIA!

Comment: Uhm I don't think that it is signaled to applications. And probably shells / window managers do not signal it through DBus. You may write a shell extension. For example, for GNOME there is the active-workspace-changed signal: https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/meta4~4_api/meta.workspacemanager

Comment: @lb90, I am not looking to get the signal in my application - I was thinking more receiving the GTK/Qt notification itself. The reason is - I want to distinguish between regular window minimize, when I click on the `Minimize` button and workspace switch (in this case the window is minimized as well).